# Source code listing with frame around code?

Tags: listings, framed

I'd like to make my code listing looking more sexy. I found a good example on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/741985/329637), but one problem is remaining:

I would like to not only have a horizontal line at the bottom of the listing but also at the left and right side. Therefore I changed frame=b to frame = blr. This works fine, but the problem is now that there is a small gap between the vertical lines and the caption box. How can I correct this? I want a closed box with a caption around my listing.

Comment: {looking-sexiy} may be nice, but {framed} is even better. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I thought it is time for a tag to indicate questions that want to make a latex document looking more sexy ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}\vskip-4pt}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\lstset{frame=lrb,xleftmargin=\fboxsep,xrightmargin=-\fboxsep}

\begin{document}
\belowcaptionskip=-10pt
\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly the problem I have. If you look at the screenshot I made with your solution (http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/4317/testht.png) there is a gap between the vertical lines and the caption header. I wan't to remove this gap if possible.

Comment: @Herbert: it looks if I add the following `\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\tdima
\newlength\tdimb
\setlength\tdima{ \fboxsep+\fboxrule}
\setlength\tdimb{-\fboxsep+\fboxrule}
` and then the listings options `frame = tlrb,
xleftmargin = \tdima,
xrightmargin = \tdimb,` if it works

Comment: @Danie Els Thanks this works, but I has a line on the top that is not looking really nice. Can I remove it somehow?

Comment: @Roflcoptr:  Make it the same color as the caption?, `rulecolor= \color{gray},`

Comment: @Danie Els but then all lines are this color? And where do I have to put this?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I edited my answer ...

Comment: That's great! Is it possible to "break" the `verbatim`-style, such that I can use formulas inside it? (In my case, I need to use solely `\Rightarrow`)

Comment: read the documentation. Search for `mathescape`

Answer (score 13):

Although `listings` already offers tools for framed listings, I think `tcolorbox` is far more flexible for this task. In particular, `tcolorbox` can produce framed boxes for code listings processed/created with `listings`, `listingsutf8` and `minted`.

Next code shows an example with the OP's desired `sexy` listing:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{sexylisting}[2][]{sharp corners, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries, colframe=gray, listing only, 
    listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=java}, 
    title=Listing \thetcbcounter: #2, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{sexylisting}{Some Code}
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{sexylisting}

\begin{sexylisting}[colback=white]{Same code again}
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{sexylisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like there's a lot of space before and after the code (Hence, it takes up quite some space on my paper). Is there any way to fix this? Or it's supposed to look better like that?

Comment: @pineapple    You can change tcolorbox inner margins with top, left, bottom, right and boxsep values. Try with `top=0pt, bottom=0pt, boxsep=0pt` and decide what you prefer.