# How to automatically arrange an unknown number of images?

Tags: graphics, automation

I have several compilable LaTeX input files and their corresponding PDF files. Each PDF file contains any number of pages. I want to import each LaTeX input file with `\lstinputlisting` followed by its PDF pages as images. I have to consider

- the number of pages for each PDF file on the fly,
- the available spaces for the images

to avoid getting trimmed/cropped output.

The following is my MWE. Determining the number of PDF pages per file on the fly has been solved. The remaining task is to automatically arrange the imported PDF pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{etoolbox,ifpdf,ifxetex}

\ifxetex
    \newcount\pdflastximagepages
    \def\pdfximage#1{\pdflastximagepages=\XeTeXpdfpagecount"#1"\relax}
\fi


\newcommand\Directory{}

\newcommand{\InsertOutput}[1]{%
            \IfFileExists{\Directory/#1.pdf}{%
                    \pdfximage{\Directory/#1.pdf}%
                    \multido{\i=1+1}{\the\pdflastximagepages}
                        {\includegraphics[page=\i]{\Directory/#1}}
            }{The corresponding PDF file does not exist.}%
}



\begin{document}

\renewcommand\Directory{Contents}
\InsertOutput{Article}

\end{document}
```

Pages in a single PDF file have the same dimension. I might need scaling factor to arrange the images. Each PDF file might need different scaling factor but the same factor will be used for the pages in a single PDF file. I prefer no more than 2 images in one row.

I skipped the usage of `\lstinputlisting` code for the sake of simplicity.

Using `pdfpages` package is not my option because I need the images floats and fill the available space.

### The real scenario

I want to write a tutorial on LaTeX showing the code followed its output.
As `LTXexample` from `showexpl` does not work well for a compilable LaTeX input file, I have to use `\lstinputlisting` and `\includegraphics`.
The problem is to arrange the images following the imported code.

I want to produce a tutorial like below. FOR EXAMPLE, the page `n` contains a source code and `2m` images, the  page `n+1` may contain the remaining images and some sentences as the corresponding comments, with `m` and `n` are integers.

[image]

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Could you provide a specimen of a beautifully arranged page? Can the included PDF files have different page sizes? One of the most important factors for arrangement will be the relation between the size of the included PDF and the page they are to be arranged on.

Comment: I think Yiannis Lazarides is the person you are looking for :)

Comment: Look at `pdfpages` package and its layout options.

Comment: @Forgiver Sorry, but I don't understand your comment: what thing do you want to float?

Comment: The code in your question solves the problem, doesn't it? You only have to add [width=0.5\linewidth] or a similar option to each \includegraphics, so that you can have several pages per row. Or perhaps you are asking about how to find the appropiate value instead of 0.5?

Comment: @Forgiver. I think that you mean "reflow" instead of "float". Floating consist on move the images to the next available space (usually on top of the next page), and then reflow the text to fill the gap. This is what latex figure environment does. I think that you want instead the images to fill the available space, so that in this case they don't float, but reflow, like text. I.e. each image must be treated by tex as a simple character (although a very big one).
In this sense \includegraphics is your friend. And use width to control the size of that "character"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, there is my answer.

The idea is to make a loop which uses `\includegraphics` to output each page of the pdf, at 45% of the line width (assuming that you want two pages per row, which seems sensible). The tricky part is to consider the case of an odd number of pages. In this case, the last row contains a single page, so it would be nicer if that page is centered.

The following code does that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{repeat}

\lstset{ %
    frame=single,
    language=tex,                    % the language of the code
    numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,         % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize, % font and size of the code
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces adding particular underscores
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    tabsize=4,                       % sets default tabsize to 4 spaces
    breaklines=false,                % sets automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
}

\def\IncludeOutput#1{
  \parskip=2mm
  \def\examplename{#1}
  \pdfximage{\Directory/\examplename.pdf}%
  \edef\lastpdfpage{\the\pdflastximagepages}
  \repeat\for{pag}\by{0} % We advance manually the counter in the loop body
  \until{\ifnum\pag>\lastpdfpage}
  \do{
    \noindent\hfill\fbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,page=\number\pag]{\Directory/\examplename.pdf}}%
    \hfill%
    \advance\pag by 1
    \ifnum\pag>\lastpdfpage\hfill\par% If odd number of pages
    \else% If even number of pages, output the last one
       \fbox{%
         \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth,page=\number\pag]{\Directory/\examplename.pdf}}%
       \hfill\hbox{}\par % Next pair of images
    \fi%
    \advance\pag by 1
  }
}


\begin{document}
    \def\Directory{Examples}
    \lstinputlisting{\Directory/Lipsum.tex}
    \IncludeOutput{Lipsum}
    And more text follows\dots
\end{document}
```

An this is the result:
[image]

In case the text is unreadable, the content of `Lipsum.tex` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\maketitle
% This inserts paragraphs 1 to 35 of ``Lorem Ipsum'' which produces 7 pages
  \lipsum[1-35]
\end{document}
```

And you can download the resulting pdf [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c48zdbh7stiajaw/custom-layout-pdf.pdf)

Comment: The idea to have the two images "evenly spaced between the margins" is to have in each line `\hfill`[PAGE1]`\hfill`[PAGE2]`\hfill`. Those hfills expand to the same amount and then the pages are centered and evenly spaced. However, this require an empty box at the end of the third `\hfill`. Without it, `\par` would discard that space and the two pages will be "pushed" to the right margin. Try it :-)

Comment: Yes, plain tex and latex define \null as \hbox{}

Answer (score 4):

[`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) provides command `\tcbinputlisting` which does all the work for you.

Let's supose that you have the file `Lipsum.tex` (taken from JLDiaz answer) already compiled. If you want to include into another document the code and the result, use `\tcbinputlisting` with options `listing file=Lipsum` and `listing and comment`. `listing` includes tex source and `comment` the pdf result.

In case you want to get similar results but with LaTeX code into the main document it's also possible to do it. Some examples are explained in section "Option Keys for Processing and Full Document Examples" from `tcolorbox` documentation.

Next code shows a solution with external files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\tcbinputlisting{
enhanced jigsaw, breakable, pad at break*=2mm, height fixed for=first and middle,
lower separated=false,
leftlower=0pt, rightlower=0pt, middle=0pt,
colframe=red!50!black, colback=yellow!10!white,
listing and comment,
listing file={Lipsum},
listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!70!black}},
pdf comment,
comment style={raster columns=3, colframe=blue, drop fuzzy shadow},
}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The result looks like

[image]