# What makes a loop inside \IfFileExists fail?

Tags: loops

The following MWE is the simplified version of [my project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62269/9467). But it is complete enough to produce the problem. If you disable (comment) the looping parts, compilation succeed. Otherwise you will get compilation error. What makes a loop inside `\IfFileExists` fail?

```
\documentclass{book}
\input{repeat}

\def\Foo{%
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.tex}{%
    \repeat\for{x}\by{0}%
    \until{\ifnum\x>10}%
    \do{\advance\x by 1}%
  }%
  {%
    File not found.
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\Foo
\end{document}
```

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (Web2C 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./dj.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nyn
orsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbia
nc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorb
ian, welsh, loaded.
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/eijkhout/repeat.tex
Loading loop macro, version 0.93a) (./dj.aux))
! Incomplete \ifeof; all text was ignored after line 16.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> dj.tex

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> dj.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on dj.log.
```

Comment: Is there any comment to improve my question?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it's noteworthy. Loading the *repeat* file or package (although it isn't a LaTeX package) can potentially cause problems in a LaTeX document, which is exactly what you have. The command `\repeat`, which is central in *repeat* file is defined in the LaTeX kernel as `\fi`, which allows Knuth's (and LaTeX's) `\loop` to be nested in a conditional. Note: "nested in a conditional" doesn't mean nesting `\loop` in itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Ahmed noted the repeat.tex macros are incompatible with latex, Plain and LaTeX loops already use `\repeat` so redefining it will break those. (Perhaps most notably `\multicolumn` relies on this.

Unlike most LaTeX conditional command the true and false blocks are actually handled *inside* a primitive `\if.... \else ....\fi` construct (rather than just using the conditionaal to execute `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo`). This means that the code in the true and false branches each need to be well balanced with respect to `\if.. \fi` tokens. But your code has an unmatched `ifnum` which would not be a problem if executed by the repeat macro but means that the code can not be skipped over, hence the error that you quote.

---

If you *really* want to use such a construct you have to move the loop out of the true/false arguments, as below, where `\next` is defined to do nothing or to eat the loop depending on the test, but as noted above it is not advisable to use this macro in latex.

```
\def\Foo{%
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.tjex}{%
   \let\next\relax
  }%
  {%
    File not found.
    \def\next####1\do####2{}
  }%
\next\repeat\for{x}\by{0}%
    \until{\ifnum\x>10}%
    \do{\advance\x by 1}%
}
```

Comment: +1 but is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: there are any number of repeatable loop macros, just don't use that one:-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution based on [tohecz's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62368/teach-me-how-to-use-loop-repeat-constructs-etc#comment132455_62368):

```
\documentclass{book}
\input{repeat}

\newif\ifFE

\def\Foo{%
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.tex}{\FEtrue}{\FEfalse}
    \ifFE
        \repeat\for{x}\by{0}%
        \until{\ifnum\x>10}%
        \do{\the\x\advance\x by 1}%
    \else
        File not found.
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\Foo
\end{document}
```