# Teach me how to use \loop...\repeat constructs, etc

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, loops

The following code snippet is a part of the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62269/9467):

```
\def\IncludeOutput#1{
  \parskip=2mm
  \def\examplename{#1}
  \pdfximage{\Directory/\examplename.pdf}%
  \edef\lastpdfpage{\the\pdflastximagepages}
  \repeat\for{pag}\by{0} % We advance manually the counter in the loop body
  \until{\ifnum\pag>\lastpdfpage}
  \do{
    \noindent\hfill\fbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,page=\number\pag]{\Directory/\examplename.pdf}}%
    \hfill%
    \advance\pag by 1
    \ifnum\pag>\lastpdfpage\hfill\par% If odd number of pages
    \else% If even number of pages, output the last one
       \fbox{%
         \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth,page=\number\pag]{\Directory/\examplename.pdf}}%
       \hfill\hbox{}\par % Next pair of images
    \fi%
    \advance\pag by 1
  }
}
```

I want to use `\loop...\repeat` constructs in the code snippet above instead of the current looping constructs which are defined in `\input{repeat}`.

I am not familiar with `\loop...\repeat`, especially for nested loops and conditional statements such as checking whether the number is odd or even, checking whether a number is greater or equal to another number.

Comment: I think I should rollback to get useful answers.

Comment: I think your earlier MWE was much more M, though I suppose just as little W.  This one has too much going on.

Comment: It would be nicer if you explained *what* you want to achieve.

Comment: @egreg: I want to make [the answer given by JLDiaz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62269/9467) still work if I enclose  it with `\IfFileExists`.

Comment: @HiggsBoson I believe you can use the following workaround: `\newif\ifFE \IfFileExists{myfile}{\FEtrue}{\FEfalse}  \ifFE ... \else ... \fi`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This doesn't work with Knuth's TeX, because it requires e-TeX's `\unless`; but `pdftex` has it.

```
\newcount\X
\X=10

\loop
\the\X\endgraf
\advance \X by -1
\unless\ifnum \X<0
\repeat

\bye
```

There are no predefined operators for combining conditionals.

Loops with `\loop...\if...\repeat` are really easy:

```
\loop
<codeA>
<conditional>
<codeB>
\repeat
```

Usually one has either `<codeA>` or `<codeB>`, but not both (it's allowed to have both, though). The main difference is that `<codeA>` is always executed at least once, because it comes *before* the conditional.

What's the conditional? Any predefined or built one;  `<codeA>` and `<codeB>` can also contain complete conditionals.

The `\repeat` command is defined (in LaTeX) as `\fi`, so that a loop can be nested in another conditional. Thus

```
\newif\ifhiggs

\IfFileExists{abc.tex}{\higgstrue}{\higgsfalse}
\ifhiggs
  \loop
  <codeA>
  <conditional>
  <codeB>
  \repeat
\fi
```

is a good way to avoid complicated code in the argument. You can even use Eijkhouts `repeat.tex` provided you redefine `\repeat`:

```
\input{repeat}
\let\Repeat\repeat
\let\repeat\fi
```

and use `\Repeat` instead of `\repeat` for the loops. However, I cannot recommend using that loop construction.

Answer (score 9):

X >= 0 is the same as X>-1:

```
\newcount\X
\X=10
\loop
\the\X\endgraf
\advance \X by -1
\ifnum \X>-1
\repeat
\bye
```

or with a dummy value

```
\newcount\X
\newcount\Y
\X=10
\Y=0
\loop
\the\X\endgraf
\advance \X by -1
\ifnum\X>0 \ifnum\X=0\Y=1\fi\else\Y=1\fi
\ifnum\Y=0
\repeat
\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

Yo can also use the math library that is part of `pgf`:

[image]

### References:

- [How to test if a number is negative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15297/how-to-test-if-a-number-is-negative)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand{\TestValue}[2]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\var}{#1-#2}%
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\var>=0,"#1~is greater or equal to #2","#1~is less than #2")}
\pgfmathresult%
}%

\begin{document}
\TestValue{11}{10}\par
\TestValue{10}{10}\par
\TestValue{9}{10}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Yo can" -> "You can"

Answer (score 3):

Raw TeX does not have amenities such as compound Boolean operators.  Instead, you must nest your conditionals:

```
\newcount\X
\X=10

\newif\ifGEzero
\loop
\the\X\endgraf
\advance \X by -1
% The spaces after the 0's are important
\ifnum\X>0 \GEzerotrue
\else
 \ifnum\X=0 \GEzerotrue
 \else\GEzerofalse
 \fi
\fi
\ifGEzero
\repeat

\bye
```

The reason I made a `\newif` was because the `\loop` syntax forbids compound conditionals!  Instead, you execute the whole conditional in the loop body, storing the logical result in the `\ifGEzero` test, and then begin that conditional as the loop condition.  (See my answer to [What is `\iffalse` for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46383/575) for a philosophical explanation of this.)

Answer (score 2):

Solved! It is time to sleep.

```
\newcount\x
\newcount\M
\newcount\N


\M=7% number of pages.
\N=\M
\advance\N by 1
\x=1

\loop
    \ifnum\x<\N
    \noindent\null\hfill page:\the\x
    \advance \x by 1
    \ifnum\x>\M
        \hfill\null\endgraf
    \else
        \hfill page:\the\x\hfill\hbox{}\endgraf
    \fi
    \advance \x by 1
\repeat

\bye
```

Comment: My answer based on combining the existing answers.