# Combine many files in LyX

Tags: lyx, combine, format-files

I have written dozens of exercises as LyX documents in separate files. Each of them has its own unique number. For example: 1013, 2053 etc. I would like to create a booklet with all the exercises, arranged by their exercise number. Is there a good way to combine them without inserting files manually one after the other? and also is there a way to arrange their order ascending by exercise number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear what you want to achive. The following code includes all files `<num>.pdf` where `<num>` goes from start to end value, these values can be easily modified in the code. For details about how `\loop...\repeat` works, see [Teach me how to use \loop...\repeat constructs, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62368/teach-me-how-to-use-loop-repeat-constructs-etc) .

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\newcount\x
\x=3 % start value
\loop
\ifnum\x<10 % end value
\IfFileExists{\the\x.pdf}{\includepdf[pages=-]{\the\x.pdf}}{}
\advance\x1
\repeat

\end{document}
```