# How to Use (Install) the igo (CTAN) Package

Tags: fonts, packages, ctan

Up to a few days ago, all of my knowledge about importing packages was based on using `\usepackage{}` with the packages installed by whatever distribution you'd end up using. Now, I'm kind of confused as to how it all works.

I'm trying to use 2 packages: [`psgo`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/psgo/) and [`igo`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/igo), they both aim at creating Go (board game) diagrams.

The `psgo` package seems to come with TeX Live, but I'm not sure. I had both of them "installed" locally — I actually just downloaded them from the mirrors and placed them in folders inside [my template project](https://github.com/psygo/latex-go-diagrams-template). Now apparently `\usepackage{psgo}` seems to be working.

For `igo`, I did a similar thing, trying out many different variations:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{./igo/igo}

\begin{document}
  \white{b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,g3,g2,c3}
  \black{b3,b2,c2,d3,e3,f3,f2}
  \begin{center}
    \shortstack{\showgoban\\White to kill}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, when I try to compile things, it complains about fonts:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./src/igo.template.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./igo/igo.sty

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
++++++++++++ igo.sty - January 2007 - 0.62 +++++++++++ 
+ A TeX package to manipulate Go games and positions + 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/eijkhout/repeat.tex
Loading loop macro, version 0.93a)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm igo10
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input igo10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf igo10
! I can't find file `igo10'.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input igo10
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input igo10
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: igo10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input igo10' failed to make igo10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \igo@font=igo10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.175 \smallgoban
                 
?
```

Shouldn't importing fonts be done internally within the package itself? The `igo` package even comes with a folder with fonts.

Anyway, is there a way for me to fix this "from the outside"? Am I really understanding this package installation problem correctly?

Comment: the package is not in texlive (probably licence issues) but you need to install the fonts as well as the .sty (you can put them all in the document directory assuming everything is available)

Comment: don't use a subdirectory `./igo/igo.sty` put the files directly in the current directory and use `\usepackage{igo}` that will simplify things greatly

Comment: Is there no way of doing things in a more organized fashion? Putting all things in the same directory is gonna make things so messy for me.

Comment: sure but get it working first, putting it in a subdirectory of the current directory complicates everything as, as you show, metafont and other programs won't know to look there. if it works in the current directory you can install it all in a local texmf tree such as `~/texmf/fonts/igo` or whatever,  but one step at a time

Comment: I see. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try it and come back soon, hopefully.

Comment: be careful. Igo loads repeat.tex which breaks loops in LaTeX. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652011/2388

Comment: Do **NOT** run `updmap` if you install the fonts locally. There's no map file anyway that I can see, but trying to install one may cause other problems later. Note that the fonts are unlikely to be satisfactory for electronic documents because they are not vector.

Comment: Gosh, these ancient two packages grow more and more annoying with me. I'm gonna create something similar with TikZ in the near future for sure.

Comment: I've tried to do as @DavidCarlisle recommended, but it doesn't seem to change anything apparently. I get the same error messages about fonts. Has anyone been able to maybe fork my repo and see how it goes? I wonder how that guy in the post Ulrike Fischer mentioned managed to get it working...

Comment: Are any of you interested in helping with an answer if I add a bounty to this question?