# Specifying the width and height of a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to specify the width and height of a `tikzpicture`? To scale a `tikzpicture` I use the option `scale`, i.e. for instance

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried to change the width and height as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[width = 2in, height = 3in]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but this gives me an error "I do not know the key /tikz/width".

Comment: With a `tikzpicture`, you specify all the coordinates, so the picture is as big as needed. With `pgfplots`, the size of the plot is computed, so you can specify the `width` and `height` options to the `axis` environment within a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes. I am not using pgfplots though. I should have not tagged the question with pgfplots. I have removed the tag now.

Comment: Ok, but I was trying to explain why it does not make sense to specify the `height`/`width` of a `tikzpicture`, but does make sense to be able to specify the `height`/`width` of a `pgfplots` graph.  With a `tikzpicture` only the `scale` option makes sense.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok. Yes I understood.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth

Answer (score 73):

**EDIT:**

I came back here to add information about the `tikzscale` package, however I found [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320521/19096) about that already in this thread. I believe you will want to give it a try.

---

Use `resizebox` outside of `tikzpicture`.

```
\resizebox{width}{height}{object}
```

For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node [draw] (my node 1) {my node 1};
                \node [draw, anchor = west] (my node 2) at (my node 1.east) {centro};
                \node [draw, anchor = west] at (my node 2.east) {my node 3};
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But in this solution also things like line widths and font sizes get resized, right? In this case graphics would no longer stay consistent when they have to be resized by different amounts.

Comment: I agree with you, but doing so is the purpose of the question, no?

Comment: Not sure about that. I could imagine that the intention is that you can draw your graphic in any relative coordinates or units of measure such that it is automagically sized to a certain width or height. Of course this should happen in a way that the line widths and fonts keep their sizes. Theoretically you could achieve that by drawing everything in units of a variable ``\picturewidth`` or so, but this would be rather unconvenient.

Comment: Oh I forgot before: I think the idea is that you don't  have to care that much about how large your graphic will get at the end. Instead you can just start drawing and will in most cases end up with a graphic that has the desired width or height.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that labels get resized too. For example if I only change the height or width then the labels look stretched.

Comment: @Spenhouet If you set only the width or the height, and set the other to `!`, then the image will be resized without changing the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 32):

Converting my comments to an answer as I think question is more about specifying a `height`, `width` option rather than *how* to scale  picture to get it to be of the appropriate size.

### Summary:

It does *not* make sense to specify the `height`/`width` of a `tikzpicture`, but *does* make sense to be able to specify the `height`/`width` of a `pgfplots` graph. With a `tikzpicture` only the `scale` option makes sense.

### Explanation:

Within a `tikzpicture`, you specify all the coordinates, so the picture is as big as needed. So, if you say draw a line from `(0,0) to (4,0)` you get a line that is `4cm` long (`cm` being the default unit of measurement).
So applying a scale factor of say `0.5` would make this line `2cm` long.
But what does it mean to say draw a line of `4cm` in a box that is `2cm wide`?
Perhaps you want to only view the parts of the picture in the first `2.0cm`, then you are clipping the picture, and there is a macro to do that called `\clip`.

Now, by default the units are assumed to be `cm`, so (4,0) corresponds to `4cm` in the x-direction. There is an option to specify to use different units with the `x=<length>`, but again this is scaling.

However, with graphing packages such as `pgfplots`, the size of the plot is computed, and one can make a determination as to what physical size corresponds to a unit in each of the axis directions. So, for the case of plotting graphs it makes perfect sense to have options to specify the `height`, or `width` of the graph.

So, in my mind it does *not* make sense to have options to specify the `height` or `width` of a `tikzpicture` but does make sense to be able to apply a `scale` option.  For graphing environments such as `pgfplots` it makes prefect sense to be able to specify a `height`, and `width`, and these are available in the `axis` environment options.

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't it make sense to draw the picture, then scale it by whatever factor gives `width = \textwidth`?

Comment: @mrc: Perhaps my answer was not clear: It _does_ make sense to scale a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: I'm sure I misunderstood your answer. I know you said scaling makes sense, but why not scaling by specifying what the width should be after the picture is scaled?

Comment: @mrc: Sorry for the delayed response. When you specify to `tikz` that a picture should consist of a horizontal line that is 1cm long, and a scale=0.5, and that the width of the picture be 3cm, which one is supposed to determine how wide the picture is?  Perhaps what you are asking about is [How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth).

Comment: I certainly wouldn't expect to be able to specify  `scale=0.5` and `width=3cm` simultaneously. The question you linked to is interesting. Still, I would have expected that `tikz` would accept keys like `width=0.8\textwidth` . . . the behavior I would expect is that `tikz` would draw the unscaled picture, then scale it proportionally so that the width has the desired value. I didn't look too carefully---that seems to be what is described in the question you linked to---I am just confused about why that isn't the default behavior of `tikz`.

Comment: I have a case where I use `\mathrlap` and what is inside that command is not impacting the size of the picture. So there are case where specifying the dimensions (not a scaling) could help as it would allow to have the picture big enough to display what is inside the `\mathrlap{}` command.

Comment: @Togh: Without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) it is hard to respond to your comment. The content within the`\mathrlap is not really something that should be scaled and I would use `\widthof` to adjust any sizing of the equations to ensure that the contents width was noticed where it was needed.

Comment: @Peter Grill It was more to comment on the fact that one may want to have some control over the dimensions of a `tikzpicture` without changing the scaling (so basically adding some white space around).
But I don't pretend it's a good idea to come to that kind of wish.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is a rather old post, but it did show up in google as a first result, so I want to add one solution here that is still missing.

If you have your tikzpicture in a individual file, like in Tom Bombadil's answer, you can use the package [tikzscale](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale). Then in your document you can use

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mytikzpic}
```

The file `mytikzpic.tikz` only includes the tikzcode:

```
%mytikzpic.tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}

%some tikz code

\end{tikzpicture}
```

`tikzscale` uses an iterative approach to scale the picture to the desired size, thereby compiling the picture code several times. This will lengthen the compile time of the document. It works well with `tikz` externalize library though, with which one can save most of that overhead again.

Comment: How do you obtain a `.tikz` file given a `.tex` file containing `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: Again, very much too late, but you simply save the file with the ending ".tikz"...

Comment: Giving error: "Package tikzscale Error: Requested to scale unscalable graphic"

Comment: On overleaf at least includegraphics doesn't recognise the ticz file as as a supported graphics format

Comment: Worth noting that when your `mytikzpic.tikz` is located in another directory, it is required to specify the file extension to the file as well.

Answer (score 15):

Simply consider using the PGFplots keys `/pgfplots/width` and `/pgfplots/width` as follows.

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=.8\textwidth,
    height=.8\textheight,
    ]
  ...
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

More details in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) (search for the aforementioned keys, circa page 295).

Comment: ...but this is what the OP suggests doesn't work...

Comment: also this is `pgfplots` syntax and TikZ doesn't know these options.

Comment: this works for me :)

Comment: @Werner, the OP was using them in the tikzpicture environment. This answer specifically indicated to use these in the axis environment.

Comment: @percusse, sure it does: PGF is to TikZ what TeX is to LaTeX.

Comment: @vitaminace33 OP not using pgfplots https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75449/specifying-the-width-and-height-of-a-tikzpicture/156901#comment161357_75449, TikZ uses pgf, but pgfplots is something else (which does use pgf/TikZ).

Answer (score 10):

This uses part of my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74347/is-it-possible-to-make-an-image-gallery-with-tikz-images/74495#74495): first, the image is drawn virtually to get the scaling factors, then it is drawn using these factors.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\getsizes}[2]% width, height
{   \path (current bounding box.south west);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xsw}{\ysw}
    \path (current bounding box.north east);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xne}{\yne}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\picwidth}{(\xne-\xsw)/28.453}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\picheight}{(\yne-\ysw)/28.453}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\picxscale}{#1/\picwidth}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\picyscale}{#2/\picheight}
    \xdef\xsca{\picxscale}
    \xdef\ysca{\picyscale}
}

\newcommand{\xyscaledtikz}[3]% draw commands, width, height
{ \smash{\vphantom{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        #1
        \getsizes{#2}{#3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\xsca,yscale=\ysca]
        #1
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.tex}
\draw[rotate=30,left color=red,right color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\xyscaledtikz{\input{picone}}{2}{3}
\xyscaledtikz{\input{picone}}{6}{1}

\xyscaledtikz{\input{picone}}{2}{7}
\xyscaledtikz{\input{picone}}{4}{4}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Very good. If you just want to scale to a given height but leave the aspect ratio, replace `xscale=\xsca` by `xscale=\ysca`. The same applies for defining width and compute height automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like `\draw[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (3,2)` or(`\path`) if you don't want to draw) to change the aspect ratio of your image, then use `scale` to change the size. But I agree with Benedikt and Peter that scaling the dimensions separately will warp the picture you are trying to draw, and that you should probably not be looking for such an option in the first place.

Comment: Nice. Most of the time I resort to this hack. I define a command like `\newcommand*{\setbbox}{\path[use as bounding box] (-2,-1.8) rectangle (4.2,4);}` whose dimensions must be tweaked on a case by case basis (sigh). Then inside each tikzpicture I start with `\setbbox`. It's not very pretty, but it's quick to set up.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it might make sense to specifically define the width and height. For example, I want to create an image for a presentation that adds new elements on each slide. So I want the different images to be the same size in order not to move around the slide. My workaround is to define a white spot somewhere in the right, lower corner that is not visible in the images but keeps the size constant for all images. The position of the spot will then define the width and height of the image.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how useful this will be to others, but I found adding a node that defines a minimum width and height worked pretty well for me. I needed this because one of my nodes was of a variable width, but I needed the image to be anchored to the bottom right of the page.

The code would look like:

```
\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0,anchor=east,minimum width=8.75in, minimum height=112pt] {};
```

Make sure to change the `anchor` as needed.

The downside here is that if any of your nodes go outside the area defined by the first node, you picture will still grow to be larger. You might be able to avoid that by using the `\clip` option inside a scope, but I didn't experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is the package `adjustbox`. You can place the `tikzpicture` into it to resize it. It also scales text, so it is very similar to what you would get from `includegraphics`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following workaround to set a fixed width and height of a tikzpicture.

- I set the tikzfigure scale fixed to 1
- I draw an invisible line in the diagonal of the picture `\path[draw=none] (0,0) -- (width,height);`
- I then draw the rest of the picture in that canvas.

If you had already drawn the picture before setting the invisible canvas line, you can shift the invisible path, or rescale the rest of the nodes within the tikzpicture to make it fit the canvas.