# Scaling issues with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I have two Tikz block code one after the other in my document in an enumerated list, Why does the following code scale the two Tikz figure differently? I am using the tkz-euclide package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}

Find the area of the triangle:
\vspace{-1em}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{2.5in}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Q) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at ($(Q)+(40:5)$);
\coordinate (P) at ($(Q)+(150:4)$);
\draw (A) -- (Q) -- (P) -- cycle;
\tkzLabelPoint[below](Q){$Q$};
\tkzLabelPoint[right](A){$A$};
\tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$};
\path (A) -- node [midway,above] {$11$} (P);
\path (A) -- node [midway,below right] {$9$} (Q);
\path (P) -- node [midway,below left] {6} (Q);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}

The diagram below is the plan of a field. Find the area of the field.
\vspace{-1em}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{2.5in}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (P) at (0,0);
\coordinate (S) at ($(P)+(-20:2)$);
\coordinate (Q) at ($(P)+(110:2)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(P)+(45:2.5)$);
\draw (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- (S) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (P) -- (R);
\tkzLabelPoint[left](Q){$Q$};
\tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$};
\tkzLabelPoint[right](S){$S$};
\tkzLabelPoint[right](R){$R$};
\path (P) -- node [midway,sloped,above] {$650$} (R);

\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](P,Q,R){$56^\circ$};
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](P,Q,R);
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](S,P,R){$44^\circ$};
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](S,P,R);
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](R,P,Q){$83^\circ$};
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](R,P,Q);
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](P,R,S){$65^\circ$};
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](P,R,S);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At a glance, the `\resizebox` command scales each tikz picture to be 2.5in wide.  Have you tried removing this command?

Comment: Use `scale` instead, as specifying width/height is not a good idea. To quote [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75507/73830): "It does not make sense to specify the height/width of a `tikzpicture`, but does make sense to be able to specify the height/width of a pgfplots graph. With a `tikzpicture` only the scale option makes sense."

Comment: Jak123, Isn't scaling bad for Tikz pictures, because it doesn't scale the text? What would be a good way to make all the picture the same size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your original drawings (before scaling) were one much bigger and one much smaller than your desired size. You should try something like the `scale` option or the `x=legth,y=length`, which does not mess with the text.

(p.s. i'm not familiar with tkzMarkAngle but it sounds somehow wrong to specify size in cm instead of the figure units)

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  \usetkzobj{all}


  \begin{document}

    Find the area of the triangle:
    \vspace{-1em}
    \begin{center}
      %\resizebox{2.5in}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
          \coordinate (Q) at (0,0);
          \coordinate (A) at ($(Q)+(40:5)$);
          \coordinate (P) at ($(Q)+(150:4)$);
          \draw (A) -- (Q) -- (P) -- cycle;
          \tkzLabelPoint[below](Q){$Q$};
          \tkzLabelPoint[right](A){$A$};
          \tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$};
          \path (A) -- node [midway,above] {$11$} (P);
          \path (A) -- node [midway,below right] {$9$} (Q);
          \path (P) -- node [midway,below left] {6} (Q);
        \end{tikzpicture}%}
    \end{center}

    The diagram below is the plan of a field. Find the area of the field.
    \vspace{-1em}
    \begin{center}
      %\resizebox{2.5in}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
          \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
          \coordinate (S) at ($(P)+(-20:2)$);
          \coordinate (Q) at ($(P)+(110:2)$);
          \coordinate (R) at ($(P)+(45:2.5)$);
          \draw (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- (S) -- cycle;
          \draw[dashed] (P) -- (R);
          \tkzLabelPoint[left](Q){$Q$};
          \tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$};
          \tkzLabelPoint[right](S){$S$};
          \tkzLabelPoint[right](R){$R$};
          \path (P) -- node [midway,sloped,above] {$650$} (R);

          \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](P,Q,R){$56^\circ$};
          %\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](P,Q,R);
          \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65](P,Q,R);
          \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](S,P,R){$44^\circ$};
          %\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](S,P,R);
          \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65](S,P,R);
          \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](R,P,Q){$83^\circ$};
          %\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](R,P,Q);
          \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65](R,P,Q);
          \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](P,R,S){$65^\circ$};
          %\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65cm,](P,R,S);
          \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.65](P,R,S);
        \end{tikzpicture}%}
    \end{center}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Davide, Thanks for your solution. I appreciate the explanation.!!!

Comment: Davide, is there a trick to figuring out the scaling for each picture so that all your image sizes are the same without trial and error? Or is there a better option than scaling? According to jak123 above, scaling is the best option.

Comment: nothing that I can think of right now... besides maybe considering the distances you use in your picture (4 and 5 in the first, 2 and 2,5 in the second). there could be a convoluted way of drawing first, then resizing, then adding an overlay with text - but i wouldn't know how to do that right now, I would have to check the manual and invest some time - which unfortunately I'm rather scarce of now =(

Answer (score 5):

Firstly  `\resizebox`is a bad idea because you scale all objects (points, lines and fonts). Davide answer is correct you need to use `scale option`from tikZ.

I put my code because `tkz-euclide` has a special syntax without `;` and some commands can be simplify.
You don't need to load `Tikz`because `pgfplots and Tkz-Euclide` use `TikZ`
If the big part of your code use `TikZ`why use `tkz-euclide`. It's a lot of code useless. Then when you use `tkz-euclide`, `TikZ` is always behind so when you don't know how do something you can can use `Tikz` but It's preferable to avoid the mixing.
I use `mark=none` because angles are not equal.

I compile the code with the new version of [tkz-euclide is here](http://altermundus.fr/includes/fichiers.php)

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

  Find the area of the triangle:

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.8cm,y=.8cm]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Q](40:5){A}  
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[Q](150:4){P} 
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,P,Q)
  \tkzLabelPoint[below](Q){$Q$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[right](A){$A$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[swap](A,P){$11$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[](A,Q){$9$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[](Q,P){$6$}
\end{tikzpicture}

 The diagram below is the plan of a field. Find the area of the field.

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){P}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[P](-20:2){S}  
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[P](110:2){Q} 
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[P](45:2.5){R} 
    \tkzDrawPolygon(P,...,S)
  \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](P,R)
  \tkzLabelPoint[left](Q){$Q$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[right](S){$S$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[right](R){$R$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](P,R){$650$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](P,Q,R){$56^\circ$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](S,P,R){$44^\circ$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](R,P,Q){$83^\circ$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.35](P,R,S){$65^\circ$}
  \tkzMarkAngles[mark=none,size=0.65](P,R,S R,P,Q S,P,R P,Q,R)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When we can expect `tkz-euclide` Version 2.55c on CTAN? With existed  CTAN version I receive error `\tkzDrawPolygon is unknow`

Comment: I think Sunday ...  With the old version you need to place `usetkzobj{all}` in the preamble. With the new version i decide to load all the objects except protractor and show. Now the bounding box is controlled and generally you don't need to clip

Comment: @Zarko I ask in few minutes a new question about scaling because I discover yesterday a problem with my example of reference

Comment: unfortunately `\usetkzobj{all´}` cause new errors >(`Runaway argument` ... ! Paragraph ended before `pgffor@@dotscharcheck was complete` ). I need to wait for new version on CTAN :-). About scaling: this is about my knowledge ... :-(