# Missing number error with LuaLaTeX and standalone under LaTeX 2020/10/01

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, externalize

I have troubles using TikZ externalize and standalone. It seems that the required PDF is not generated. First, I suspected the recent PFG update (https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/932) but after some tests it seems to be related to standalone.

In my MWE I have four files.

file2:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass[class=report,11pt,a4paper,tikz,]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

file1:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[--shell-escape]   

\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzfiles/]
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{file2.tex}
\end{document}
```

File3:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

File0:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[--shell-escape]   

\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{file2.tex}
\end{document}
```

File2 works while file1 results in errors:

Output from main log:

```
 ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape
 -halt-on-e rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikzfiles/file1-figure0" "\def\tikzextern
 alrealjob{file1}\input{file1}"' did NOT result in a usable output file
 'tikzfil es/file1-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).
 Please verify that y ou have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this
 is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. S ometimes it is also named 'write 18' or
 something like that. Or maybe the comma nd simply failed? Error
 messages can be found in 'tikzfiles/file1-figure0.log'.  If you
 continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

Output from the log in the tikzfiles folder:

```
\providecommand \oddpage@label [2]{} ] 
! Missing number, treated as
zero. <to be read again> 
= l.11 \end{document}
```

However, calling file3 from file1 works, so the problem does not seem to be related to externalize (alone).

file0 on the other hand errors without using externalize so I suspect standalone.

And the log:

```
(./file2.tex ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>  = l.11 \end{document}
```

Comment: I get the error also with older latex and pgf, so it is not related to the newest update. Why do you use standalone and externalize together?

Comment: This is definitely unrelated to the update and looks like a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492981/compile-error-improper-prevdepth-from-epstopdf-when-trying-tikzcode-which-must/492987#492987

Comment: You are right my MWE was to simplified. The new one with two files should be better. The same code works on another machine with TL2020 but not updated recently.

Comment: As explained in Edit2, it seems to be related to standalone and not externalize. I did not dare updating my other machine so I'm still not sure if the update somehow just broke the tex setup on this machine.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit" markers on the site. Old versions of the post is available in the history anyway. Please always edit your post to show the latest version, not a series of edits. Also, use code blocks not quotes for log messages.

Comment: it fails only with luatex, and it is related to standalone.

Comment: I removed the Edit markers and updated the post to reflect the whole problem. The title might need to be changed.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I think  `\aftergroup\endinput`  in `\sa@enddocument` is too early now, it interrupts the hook code.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I added also an issue at latex3: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/813

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, this helps me a lot. I will try to update `standalone` to use the new hooks if possible.

Comment: Works now after updating texlive

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by a bug which has been fixed in current versions.