# How to set width of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, fit

I want to create the following tikzpicture:

[image]

I want the rectangle that fits around the example-image and nodes 2 and 3 to be, say, `0.6\textwidth` wide.

Moreover, I want nodes 1 and 2 to be one adjacent to the other but *centered* inside this rectangle.

I came across [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75507/) from 2012 where Peter Grill says that in his opinion it doesn't make sense to specify the height or width of a tikzpicture.

I agree with that to some extent but I don't want to wrap my tikzpicture inside a `resizebox`.

What I have now is this:

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vskip 10pt

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(n0) [draw=black,outer sep=0pt] {node 1};
\node (n1) [below right = 1pt and 0pt of n0.south west,outer sep=0pt]  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}};
\node (n2) [below right = 10pt and 20pt of n1,draw=black] {node 2};
\node (n3) [right = 1pt of n2,draw=black] {node 3};
\node (n4) [below left = 0pt and 130pt of n3.south west,outer sep=0pt,draw=black] {node 4};

%draw a rectangle as the border
\node[draw, fit=(n1) (n3),inner sep=0pt](rect1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any suggestion would be very welcome.

Comment: Do you actually need the drawn rectangle with width `.6\textwidth`? Or do you just want the picture to have a specific width centered around a point? What about the drawn line? It will add half the line width on both sides to the final width of the TikZ picture.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I want the drawn rectangle to be `.6\textwidth`; Well yes, I forgot this small detail about the addition of half the line width on both sides. Then I guess I can make the drawn rectangle to be `0.6textwidth minus edge width` or something similar.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. What should happen when the left side of the `n1` node is further away from the center of `n2` and `n3` than `.3\textwidth`?

Comment: Then the `tikzpicture` would occupy on the page a width of this "further away distance" +`.6\textwidth`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the bounding box using `\path` then place items relative to its anchors.  In this case, only the width matters until the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vskip 10pt

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) (0.6\textwidth,0);% set bounding box
\node(n0) [draw=black,outer sep=0pt, below right] at (current bounding box.west) {node 1};
\node (n1) [below right = 1pt and 0pt of n0.south west,outer sep=0pt]  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}};
\node (n2) [below left=1pt, draw=black] at (current bounding box.center |- n1.south) {node 2};
\node (n3) [right = 1pt of n2,draw=black] {node 3};
\coordinate (n4) at (current bounding box.south east);% set other corner

%draw a rectangle as the border
\node[draw, fit=(n1) (n4),inner sep=0pt](rect1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Slight simplification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vskip 10pt

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) (0.6\textwidth,0);% set bounding box
\node(n0) [draw=black,outer sep=0pt, below right] at (current bounding box.west) {node 1};
\node (n1) [below right = 1pt and 0pt of n0.south west,outer sep=0pt]  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}};
\node (n2) [below left=1pt, draw=black] at (current bounding box.center |- n1.south) {node 2};
\node (n3) [right = 1pt of n2,draw=black] {node 3};

%draw a rectangle as the border
\draw (n1.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: to have the same vertical space between node1 and the rectangle, and node3 and the rectangle, the path must be lowered by one point. \path ($(n3.south)+(0,-1pt)$);

Comment: Very nice. I don't understand what is the meaning of `\path (coord1) (coord2);`. There is no `--` between the two coordinates so it is not a line yet tikz sees it as a bounding box. Can you please briefly explain it verbally? Moreover, what are the conditions for which a `path` becomes a `current bounding box`? How do I know if I can use something as a `current bounding box`?

Comment: The `(current bounding box)` is a rectangular node fitting everything in the tikzpicture up to now, even invisible points from `\path`.  See also `\useasboundingbox` (page 184) and `local bounding box=name` (page 1143).

Comment: `\path[use as bounding box] (0,0) (.6\textwidth,0);` is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add

```
([xshift=.3\textwidth-.5\pgflinewidth]$(n2)!.5!(n3)$)
```

to the fit (and possibly

```
([xshift=-.3\textwidth+.5\pgflinewidth]$(n2)!.5!(n3)$)
```

to be on the safe side if `n1` is not `.3\textwidth` (or further) away from the center).

I've added a few rules to show that the middle of `n2` and `n3` is `.3\textwidth` away from the right side.

If no element is further to the left or right of your `rect1` node, you can also set `outer sep=0pt` for it and use `trim left=(rect1.west), trim right=(rect1.east)` as options for the TikZ picture which makes the bounding box not include half the line width on both sides.

### Code

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, fit, positioning}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vskip 10pt

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n0) [draw=black, outer sep=0pt] {node 1};
\node (n1) [below right = 1pt and 0pt of n0.south west, outer sep=0pt]
  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}};
\node (n2) [below right = 10pt and 20pt of n1, draw=black] {node 2};
\node (n3) [right = 1pt of n2, draw=black] {node 3};
\node (n4) [below left = 0pt and 130pt of n3.south west,
  outer sep=0pt, draw=black] {node 4};

%draw a rectangle as the border
\node[draw,
      fit={(n1)(n3)([xshift=.3\textwidth-.5\pgflinewidth]$(n2)!.5!(n3)$)},
      inner sep=0pt](rect1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\llap{\rule{.6\textwidth}{1pt}}%
\llap{\clap{\rule[2pt]{.1pt}{2em}}\rule[2pt]{.3\textwidth}{.5pt}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]