# tcolorbox listing error using beamers begin{frame}

Tags: beamer, listings, tcolorbox

I've just started using the tcolorbox package for slides for a LaTeX course. It works nicely to box LaTeX code, interacting with the `listings` package. However, I ran into trouble when I tried to make a box of example code for a `beamer frame`, it fails.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only} 
\begin{frame}{equation}
$a =  b$
\end{frame}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get errors "undefined control sequence \end{tcblisting}" and other errors

Commenting the `\end{frame}` before the `\end{tcblisting}` outputs ok. Also, running the code inside an `article` documentclass instead of a `beamer` class is also ok.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 8):

It's not you, it's [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)... :)

The `frame` environment is really finicky since it has to read the entire content before actually setting the frame. Why? Because when you use overlay specifications (like `\pause`, or `\only`, or `\onslide`, or ...) then the `frame` has to be broken up into different slides, each of which may require the exact same layout. So, in this instance the `\end{frame}` inside `tcblisting` is actually mistaken for the `\end{frame}` at the end of the document.

My suggestion, in cases like these, is to set the `verbatim`-like content in a box *first*, and then use that box wherever needed. Once the box is set, it's portable and should not affect "finicky things" (like `frame`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox
\newsavebox{\codebox}% To store any verbatim content

\begin{document}
% Capture the verbatim content in \codebox
\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only}
\begin{frame}{equation}
$a =  b$
\end{frame}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}{Example}

\usebox{\codebox}% Insert \codebox

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good idea to save it in a box. Perhaps I should have thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here comes another alternative.

The `tcblisting` environment saves the content into a file which is read afterwards as a listings or as a compiled text or both. This process can be decoupled:

- The environment `tcboutputlisting` saves the content into the intermediate file.
- `\tcbinputlisting` reads the intermediate file.

This gives:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcboutputlisting}
\begin{frame}{equation}
$a =  b$
\end{frame}
\end{tcboutputlisting}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example}
\tcbinputlisting{listing only}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun, I add some madness. Since the content of the listing is a code for a beamer frame, we may like to add the compiled frame inside the outer frame ...

This can be done using the compile options of `tcolorbox` which do system calls. The intermediate file has to be unique for this. In the decoupled situation here, the option `compilable listing` cannot be used and one has to take care of the file name directly. That's the reason for

```
\tcbset{listing file=\jobname-listing-myslide}
```

in the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[listings,raster,skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{listing file=\jobname-listing-myslide}% <-- Use a unique name

\begin{tcboutputlisting}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{equation}
$a =  b$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{tcboutputlisting}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example}
\tcbinputlisting{
  listing and comment,pdf comment,run pdflatex,% <-- These options do the trick
  % the rest is just to be colorful and nice:
  enhanced,oversize,
  lower separated=false,
  colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!10!white,
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!20!white},
  listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!70!black}},
  comment style={drop lifted shadow},
  sidebyside,sidebyside gap=1mm,raster columns=1
}
\end{frame}

\tcbset{listing file=\jobname.listing}% <-- reset to default

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to wrap the underlining frame into a newenvironment called `slide`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
% define a new environment called slide with two parameters.
\newenvironment{slide}[2]{%
\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=slide]{Example}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only} 
\begin{frame}{#1}
#2
\end{frame}
\end{tcblisting}
}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{equation}
{$a =  b$}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also a nice solution.