# Minted does not escape beamer's \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, minted, verbments

It seems that the following code does not work as expected (ie. printing the `\end{frame}` as a verbatim colored code.
Instead, the `\end{frame}` is interpreted by LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{frame}{Title exemple}
This is an exemple.
\end{frame}
\end{minted}
This is never shown !
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is a bunch of errors at compilation time :

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.9 \end{frame}
```

What should be done for this sample to compile nicely ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to the way that `beamer`'s `fragile` option works--it breaks with both `minted` *and* `verbments` (and anything similar).  The `fragile` option causes the contents of the frame to be written to a temp file, so that `beamer` can deal with verbatim content.  The problem is that `beamer` assumes that the current frame has ended as soon as it encounters a line beginning with `\end{frame}`.  It doesn't have a way to detect that the `\end{frame}` is actually inside a `minted` environment, and thus isn't to be taken literally.  Because of thise, both `minted` and `verbments` will fail with the example given.

There are a few ways to work around this.

- The simplest is to use `fragile=singleslide`.  This disables overlays, allowing `beamer` to avoid the use of temp files and the associated issues.
- Another solution is the approach in the answer provided by Jubobs:  just indent the environment (whether it's `minted` or `pyglist`).  Since the `\end{frame}` in the `minted` environment is now preceded by space characters, `beamer` will no longer interpret it as the end of the frame.  Unfortunately, if you take this approach, your code will be indented by one or more spaces, which may not be desirable.  You could use `minted`'s `gobble` option to work around this.  For example, if you indent by 4 spaces, then `gobble=4`.  You could also use the `autogobble` option that automatically strips off leading space characters.

Comment: The first way works for me.

Comment: Same here, using `fragile=singleslide` works well, adding space does not. I suspect that something within package `minted` has changed since the answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution (credits to [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225090/1952)) with `tcolorbox` commands `tcboutputlisting` and `tcbinputlisting`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcboutputlisting}
\begin{frame}{equation}
$a =  b$
\end{frame}
\end{tcboutputlisting}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example}
\tcbinputlisting{listing only}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method with the indentation did not work for me, and I wanted to use multiple slides. So, another possible solution is to use the `escapeinside` option of `minted` to trick Beamer into not detecting `\end{frame}`. The advantage is that you do not have to use `fragile=singleslide`.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{How to make a Beamer slide}
  \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{latex}
\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
  Body
\end{frame||}
  \end{minted}
\end{frame}
```

You can use `\end{frame||}` to end your snippet: this will escape to LaTeX but do nothing.

[image]