# \lstlistoflistings for sexylisting

Tags: pdftex, lstlisting

In this question [Source code listing with frame around code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/source-code-listing-with-frame-around-code) Ignasi provides a really nice latex snippet for code blocks. However when I use it the code block doesn't get listed in the \lstlistoflistings. It just remains empty.
Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SE.tex Please provide us a MWE with `\documentclass{}` and ´\end{document}´ thats shows your problem. This make it easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry for not including a MWE. I'll try to keep it in mind for the next post. Or should I still include one?

Comment: In almost every case it is better to include one. It will help understanding your problem much better and helpers will find a solution for your problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted the answer of @Ignasi for [Source code listing with frame around code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231710/30617) for the following solution.

Basically, `auto counter` has to be replaced by `blend into=listings`. Further, `\AtBeginDocument` is needed here:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\AtBeginDocument{
\newtcblisting[blend into=listings]{sexylisting}[2][]{sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, colframe=gray, listing only,
    listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=java},
    title=#2, #1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sexylisting}{Some Code}
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{sexylisting}

\begin{sexylisting}[colback=white]{Same code again}
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{sexylisting}

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

With these changes, the new `sexylisting` takes the original `listings` counter and may be used mixed with *normal* listings.